# Is there any way to convert columns to rows using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file which contain data like this:-

|  |  |  | Prod |  |  | Work |  |  | Vaction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | Year | 2022 | 2022 | 2023 | 2022 | 2022 | 2023 | 2022 |
|  |  | Month | 10 | 11 | 12 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 10 |
| Name | Business? | Exclusive? | Oct | Nov | Dec | Oct | Nov | Dec | Oct |
| Robert | Yes | No | 100 | 100 | 100 | 150 | 150 | 150 | 1.1 |
| Maria | No | Yes | 75 | 75 | 50 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 1 |

and I want to convert this table into this form:

| Name | Business? | Exclusive? | Year | Month | Prod | Work | Vacation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Robert | Yes | No | 2022 | Oct | 100 | 150 | 1.1 |
| Maria | No | Yes | 2022 | Nov | 100 | 150 | 1 |
| Robert | No | Yes | 2023 | Dec | 100 | 150 | 1 |
| Maria | No | Yes | 2023 | Dec | 50 | 150 | 1 |

With the help of python pandas library. I am struggling with this problem from so many days. Please Help!

Comment: pivot the dataframe

Comment: How I am not able to think the logic for that. Can you give some examples?